# How to create ASP.Net form like Oracle tabular form?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

Can anybody give me some idea about how to create an ASP.NET form like Oracle tabular form.

Like I attached below. [image]

Comment: A table with some drop downs? Select2 and a little CSS... Good luck recreating something that ugly though...

Comment: I am not thinking about the design, Austin. I am thinking about how to insert multiple data in a single Insert button, If you've experience about oracle forms developer then you can better understand...Thank you.

Comment: If it's MVC ASP at least it should all work like magic, a viewmodel that contains a list of objects where each object is everything you need on a row. Then for your controller just have the parameter for your Action as you ViewModel

Comment: Thank you Austin for sharing your Nice Idea...

Comment: You can use boostrap table and do all inputs to that table and when you hit Insert you can convert table data into JSON (or any other) and send to server to save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:GridView  ID="OracleView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" OnRowDataBound="OracleView_RowDataBound">
                                  <Columns>
                                          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="L id" DataField="id"></asp:BoundField>
                                          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Concern">
                                              <ItemTemplate>
                                                  <asp:DropDownList ID="ConcernList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:DropDownList>
                                              </ItemTemplate>
                                          </asp:TemplateField>

                                  </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
```

Inside OracleView_RowDataBound you add data to your

```
protected void OracleView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        string sql = "select Concern.name from Concern";

       /*here your connection and method read list*/
        List<string> ls = new List<string>();
        ls = return your list data;
        //ls.Insert(0, String.Empty);
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var ddl = e.Row.FindControl("ConcernList") as DropDownList;
            if (ddl != null)
            {
                ddl.DataSource = ls;
                ddl.SelectedValue = YourSelectedValueFromAnotherTable;
                ddl.DataBind();
                listDropdownMark = ls;
                selectedMeltDropdown = YourSelectedValueFromAnotherTable;
            }

        }

    }
```

Sorry if I don't help you.